# parsing boto3 describe_stacks response

Tags: python-3.x

Is there a more efficient way to parse the following response from cloudformation

I tried for loop but I am wondering if there is a better way

```
 response = {
          'Stacks': [
                      {
                        'Outputs': [
                           {
                            'Description': 'ARN of the load balancer',
                            'ExportName': 'xx',
                            'OutputKey': 'LoadBalancerARN',
                            'OutputValue': 'arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:ss'
                           },
                           {
                            'Description': 'ARN of the ecs service',
                            'ExportName': 'xxx',
                            'OutputKey': 'ServiceARN',
                            'OutputValue': 'arn:aws:ecs:5O'
                           },
                           {
                            'Description': 'ARN of the ecs task definition',
                            'ExportName': 'xxx',
                            'OutputKey': 'TaskDefinitionARN',
                            'OutputValue': 'arn:aws:ecs:xxx9'
                           }
                                       ]
                       }
                     ]
       }



def main(response):
    outputs = response['Stacks'][0]['Outputs']

    for output in outputs:     
       for k, v in output.items():        
         if 'OutputKey' in k and 'ServiceARN' in v:
          print('ServiceARN:{}'.format(output['OutputValue']))
         if 'OutputKey' in k and 'TaskDefinitionARN' in v:
          print('TaskDefinitionARN: 
          {}'.format(output['OutputValue']))    

         main(response)
```

I trying to get ServiceARN and TaskDefinitionARN values

Answer (score 0):

I found another option

```
import json

response = {}

def main(response):
  json_string = json.dumps(response)
  x = json.loads(json_string)
  for i in x['Stacks'][0]['Outputs']:
    if i['OutputKey'] == "ServiceARN":
      print(i['OutputValue'])

main(response)
```